# Filter List response in Retrofit2 ,Rxjava

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I want to filter the response list with particular string on FeedDetails using this `Observable`

```
Observable<List<FeedsDto>> listObservable = mApiService.getFeedDetails(feedsDto);
subscribe(listObservable, feedsDtoList -> view.getAllFees(feedsDtoList), throwable -> Log.e(tag, "getFeedDetails", throwable));
```

> FeedsDto as  below

```
    @SerializedName("EntryId")
    private int mEntryId;
    @SerializedName("EntryTypeId")
    private int mEntryTypeId;
    @SerializedName("FeedDetails")
    private String mFeedDetails;
    @SerializedName("FullName")
    private String mFullName;
    @SerializedName("Id")
    private int mId;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
listObservable
    .flatMapIterable(it -> it)
    .filter(feedDto -> feedDto.feedDetails().equals("string_to_filter_by"))
    .subscribe(...);
```

`flatMapIterable` -> Converts from a list of `FeedDto` objects into individual `FeedDto` objects
`filter` -> Filter them by some String/feedDetails combination

This does mean you'll no longer have a `List<FeedDto>` when you subscribe at the end, but just a stream of `FeedDto` objects.

Comment: You can add `.toList().toObservable()` to keep the list and the Observable (see my answer)

Comment: @Eselfar That's true - I just didn't include it as I was unsure about how it would work with Observables that never call `onComplete`

Comment: I have an issue with this implementation btw. How do you manage the case when there is no list at the end (none of the elements matching the filter). I get an Exception as it returns 'null'?

Comment: @Eselfar - Which bit is `null`? You can add more filtering to weed out `null` values (i.e. with `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`, or return "default" values in case you encounter an error (i.e. `onErrorResumeNext()`)

Comment: Thx. My bad, it's because I've added a map(res->res.get(0)) before the subscribe (I want the first element for some reason) and it obviously crashes when the list is empty)

Comment: If FeedsDto contains sublist then how we can iterate that subList?

Comment: @NiravJoshi Your example shows a `String` rather than another `List`. That said, you can filter it in line with `.filter(feedDto -> feedDto.getList().stream().anyMatch(element -> /*filter by something*/)))` (this assumes you're on java 8)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 mApiService.getFeedDetails(feedsDto)
    .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
    .filter(result -> result > 0) // Whatever you want to filter
    .toList()
    .toObservable()
    .subscribe(...);
```